# How to pattern match against a typeclass value?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Suppose that I define a typeclass in Haskell,

```
class (Bool a) where
    false :: a
    true  :: a
```

In order to define a generic `not` operation for any `Bool`, one would need to pattern match against its potential values:

```
not :: Bool a => a → a
not true  = false
not false = true
```

That doesn't compile, though. How can I get it to work?

Comment: You can't match against a class.  You can have an `isTrue` method in your typeclass and check against that, but you can't pattern match against the result of a method.

Comment: It's not implemented yet, but there's an open [GHC ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8583) to add typeclass-associated pattern synonyms to the `PatternSynonyms` language extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't match against a typeclass value like this. Typeclasses abstract over the actual underlying type while pattern matching would expose it.

However, you can still get the same behavior and some nice syntax with the [`ViewPatterns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns) extension. The idea is to include a function which takes your abstract value and gives you a value of a concrete type that represents a view into the structure:

```
class (Bool a) where
  true   :: a
  false  :: a
  asBool :: a -> Bool
```

Now you can use the `asBool` function in a pattern match as a view pattern:

```
not :: Bool a => a -> a
not (asBool -> True)  = false
not (asBool -> False) = true
```

However, note that this could result in `asBool` being computed twice which could be an issue if it hides an expensive computation.

Comment: But then you might have to compute `asBool` of the argument twice.

Comment: @pigworker "When the same view function is applied in multiple branches of a function definition or a case expression (e.g., in size above), GHC makes an attempt to collect these applications into a single nested case expression, so that the view function is only applied once." Although there are limits, the above case should work fine.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen The fact that it takes compiler voodoo to fix its consequences suggests that it may be a misfeature. Better to be explicit about doing the computation once.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
class CBool a where
    cfalse :: a
    ctrue  :: a
```

`cfalse` and `ctrue` are members of a type `a`, but this type can contain elements, that are not `cfalse` and `ctrue`. For example

```
instance CBool Int where
    cfalse = 0
    ctrue  = 1
```

What should `cnot 2` be? `Nothing` is a good option. Then `cnot 0 = Just 1` and `cnot 1 = Just 0`. So

```
cnot :: (CBool a, Eq a) => a -> Maybe a
cnot x | x == cfalse = Just ctrue
       | x == ctrue  = Just cfalse
       | otherwise   = Nothing
```

---

But there is another way:

```
class CIBool a where
    citrue  :: a 'True
    cifalse :: a 'False

type family Not (b :: Bool) :: Bool where
    Not False = True
    Not True  = False

data Booley :: Bool -> * where
  Falsey :: Booley False
  Truey  :: Booley True

cinot :: CIBool a => Booley b -> a b -> a (Not b)
cinot Falsey _ = citrue
cinot Truey  _ = cifalse
```

Here `CIBool` is indexed by `Bool`, `Booley` is a singleton and `cinot` is sort of dependently typed. It's possible to derive `CIBool` from `CBool`:

```
newtype a :@ b = Tag { detag :: a }
    deriving Eq

instance CBool a => CIBool ((:@) a) where
    cifalse = Tag cfalse
    citrue  = Tag ctrue
```

`(:@)` could be defined as a type family, since it's simply `Const`, but I prefer to avoid type families as much as possible. If

```
zero :: Int :@ False
zero = cifalse

one  :: Int :@ True
one  = citrue
```

then `cinot Falsey zero == one` and `cinot Truey one == zero`.

Note however, that while this is a type error:

```
zero' :: Int :@ True
zero' = cifalse
```

we can define `zero'` like this:

```
zero' :: Int :@ True
zero' = Tag 0
```

and then `cinot Truey zero' == zero`, which is senseless. Hence the `Tag` constructor should be mentioned only in the `CIBool` instance definition.

Extensions used: `{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}`.