# How to pattern match against typeclass whose instance are recursive data types?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typeclass, recursive-datastructures

This question is a follow up on [How to pattern match against a typeclass value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998729/how-to-pattern-match-against-a-typeclass-value).

I am starting up a pet project on first order logic and have decided to use Haskell for this purpose. My first hurdle is to define a 'formula of first order logic', hence the data type:

```
data Formula v  = Belong v v                      -- x in y
                | Bot                             -- False
                | Imply (Formula v) (Formula v)   -- p -> q
                | Forall v (Formula v)            -- forall x, p
```

However, I am reluctant to write code based on the implementation specifics, and would rather abstract away the details, in case I change my mind, or in case I want to reuse functionality with an alternative implementation, hence the typeclass:

```
class FirstOrder m where
  belong    :: v -> v -> m v
  bot       :: m v
  imply     :: m v -> m v -> m v
  forall    :: v -> m v -> m v
  asFormula :: m v -> Formula v
```

I have added the last function `asFormula` in order to use the `ViewPatterns` (as suggested in the above link), so as to be able to pattern match on values of this typeclass.

Now suppose I want to define a simple function:

```
subst :: (FirstOrder m) => (v -> w) -> m v -> m w
```

which substitutes variables in a formula as per a given mapping `f::v -> w` (feels like `fmap`), so the formula `belong x y` is mapped to `belong (f x) (f y)` etc. then using `ViewPatterns`:

```
subst f (asFormula -> Belong x y) = belong (f x) (f y)
```

so far so good...

However, when attempting to write `subst f p->q = (subst f p) -> (subst f q)`:

```
subst f (asFormula -> Imply p q)  = imply (subst f p) (subst f q)
```

I get a type error, which coming to think of it makes perfect sense: the pattern matching binds `p` and `q` to elements of type `Formula v` as opposed to the desired type `m v`.

Now I can see the problem, and could even think of ways of solving it by adding a `fromFormula` function to the typeclass to convert back to the type `m v`, but I am thinking this is crazy from a performance point of view (just as crazy as `asFormula` mind you), a huge price to pay in order to keep the code generic.

So here I am now, trying to define a simple function by structural recursion on a free algebra (recursive data type), but my desire to abstract away the implementation details (and write code off typeclass rather than data type) is putting me in what seems to be an impossible position.

Is there a way out, or should I just forget about abstraction and work with the recursive data type?

Comment: This might be massive overkill for your project, but if it's abstract DSLs you're looking for (and it seems like you are), then look no further: http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/TaglessStaged/beyond.pdf. You can see a fully-functioning example using this technique [here](https://github.com/cpeikert/Lol/tree/applicative-alchemy-env-in-interpreter/alchemy/Crypto/Alchemy).

Comment: @crockeea The paper looks great thank you. Even if an overkill, this is the sort of things I like to read anyway. Will definitely check out the code too.

Comment: Why've you convinced yourself that you need your `FirstOrder` class in the first place?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson No I am not saying I do need it. I just thought a class (like an interface in Java) would allow me to write code which is not tied to a particular implementation, giving more flexibility to undo possible design mistakes. So I simply tried to have a class as a matter of principle so to speak, thinking it is a good design habit. I am glad to see from your comment that it may not be a bad idea after all to use the (concrete) data type itself. Thank you !

Comment: @SvenWilliamson "Premature abstraction is the root of all evil", as they say

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson yes I can see why abstraction is an attempt at premature optimization (of the design) thank you. For my defense, the Gang of Four book does put forward the principle of 'program to an interface, not an implementation' (page 30), and it is not clear to me that FP should invalidate this (unless it is that enforcing this principle in OOP can be done at no cost).

Comment: I can see your point, however the usual way to do interfaces in Haskell is not typeclasss but records (with one field per "method").

Comment: @mb14 Oh I am new to this, never thought of that, thank you !! I will certainly follow this suggestion and see where it takes me.

Comment: You can have a look at this post : https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

Comment: @mb14 Excellent, I wanted to ask you actually coz I tried today to guess what the pattern would look like (an implementation as an instance of a record type) but wasn't very happy with my code. Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks as an overgeneralization, but let's ignore that anyway.

You can solve that with explicit F-(co-)algebras and fixed points.

```
data FormulaF v k
   = Belong v v                      -- x in y
   | Bot                             -- False
   | Imply (k v) (k v)               -- p -> q
   | Forall v (k v)                  -- forall x, p

newtype Formula v = Formula (FormulaF v Formula)      
   -- fixed point. You might not need it, but it's nice to have.
   --
```

Then, you can do

```
class FirstOrder m where
  belong    :: v -> v -> m v
  bot       :: m v
  imply     :: m v -> m v -> m v
  forall    :: v -> m v -> m v
  asFormula :: m v -> FormulaF v m
```

and

```
subst :: (FirstOrder m) => (v -> w) -> m v -> m w
subst f (asFormula -> Belong x y) = belong (f x) (f y)
subst f (asFormula -> Imply p q)  = imply (subst f p) (subst f q)
```

should now work, because `asFormula` does not convert the whole `m v` into a full formula recursively, but it converts into a `FormulaF v m` which looks as a formula superficially (the very first constructor you pattern match, like `Imply`), but deep inside still looks as a `m v`.

If you really want to pursue this overgeneral approach, maybe you should have a look at `recursion-schemes`, F-algebras and F-coalgebras, and their associated cata-/ana-/hylo-/para-/whatever morphisms.

Finally, I would suggest to avoid trying to adapt OOP design patterns in FP. Sometimes you can shoehorn something in such way, but it can often be unidiomatic. For instance, in Haskell, we are quite used to types having a fixed amount of constructors (but an open set of functions which operate on them), just like in OOP interfaces have a fixed amount of methods (but an open set of subclasses). One can try to generalize this, but it's complex, and should be done only when needed.

Comment: This is beautiful thank you! (and thanks for advice and reading suggestions)